# Find all cliques from an adjacency matrix?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have an adjacency matrix $A$, which is binary and of course square-symmetric.  How can I find all the cliques of the corresponding graph?

Comment: `FindClique[AdjacencyGraph@A, Infinity, All]`?

Comment: It should be noted that FindClique only finds maximal cliques.